# Trying to modify a code to capture an image every 15 minutes or so (time lapse)

Tags: list, opencv, python

Below code was taken from an existing post by Kieleth which I use as a subset of my larger codebase. I'm trying to leverage it to capture a list of frames taken once every thousand+ real time frames and later play in a time-lapse fashion. I've captured the frames but can't seem to view them when calling a simple function. I've seen in other posts that for loops are not recommended for this type of event but haven't figured out how to properly display. Any advise on this one would be appreciated?

````
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import cv2
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
#import threading

root = Tk()

def video_button1():# this flips between start and stop when video button pressed.
    if root.video_btn1.cget('text') == "Stop Video":
        root.video_btn1.configure(text = "Start Video")
        root.cap.release()
    elif root.video_btn1.cget('text') == "Start Video":
        root.video_btn1.configure(text = "Stop Video")
        root.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        show_frame()

def show_frame():
#    if video_btn1.cget('text') == "Stop Video":
    global time_lapse_counter
    ret, frame = root.cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1) #flip image
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img) #converts img into tkinter readable format
        root.video_label.imgtk = imgtk
        if time_lapse_counter >= 20: # for Every 20 frames, capture one into time_lapse_list
            time_lapse_list.append(imgtk)
            time_lapse_counter = 0
        root.video_label.configure(image=imgtk)
        if len(time_lapse_list) == 5: # keep only 4 frames in the list *** debug purposes.
            time_lapse_list.pop(0)
        time_lapse_counter += 1
        video_loop = root.after(40, show_frame)
    else:
        root.video_btn1.configure(text = "Start Video")

def time_lapse_play():
    root.cap.release() #stop capturing video.
    for image in time_lapse_list:  
        print (image, "  ", len(time_lapse_list),"  ",time_lapse_list) #
        #*** I see the print of the pyimagexxx but nothing appears on the video***#
        imgtk = image
        root.video_label.imgtk = imgtk
        root.video_label.configure(image=imgtk)
        cv2.waitKey(500)
#    video_loop = root.after(500, time_lapse_play)

def setup_widgets(): #simple label and 2 button widget setup
    #Setup Top Right Window with pictures
    f_width, f_height = 810, 475
    root.rightframe= Frame(root, border=0, width=f_width, height = f_height)
    root.rightframe.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=0)
    # Show video in Right Frame
    root.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    root.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, f_width)
    root.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, f_height)
    root.video_label = Label(root.rightframe)
    root.video_label.grid(row=0, column = 0)
    root.video_btn1 = Button(root.rightframe, fg='maroon', bg="yellow", text = "Stop Video", font=("Arial",10),height=0, width = 10, command=video_button1)
    root.video_btn1.grid(row=0, column = 1)
    root.video_btn2 = Button(root.rightframe, fg='maroon', bg="yellow", text="Time Lapse", font=("Arial",10),height=0, width = 10, command=time_lapse_play)
    root.video_btn2.grid(row=1, column = 1)

# Main Code
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
screen_resolution = str(screen_width)+'x'+str(screen_height)
root.geometry(screen_resolution)
time_lapse_counter = 0
time_lapse_list=[]
setup_widgets()
show_frame()
root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figure this one out. Seems that the for loop effectively doesn't work when using callback. I've modified the code to remove the for loop. I'm sure it could use some improvements but it works. I'm not sure how to reset the image count within the list as pop/append grows the list image number over time and I wonder about an overflow error. i.e after a few minutes, the list will contain [pyimage100 - pyimage200], after a few hours, [pyimage1000000 - pyimage1000100].

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()

def video_button1():# this flips between start and stop when video button pressed.
    if root.video_btn1.cget('text') == "Stop Video":
        root.video_btn1.configure(text = "Start Video")
        root.cap.release()
    elif root.video_btn1.cget('text') == "Start Video":
        root.video_btn1.configure(text = "Stop Video")
        root.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        root.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 400)
        root.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 400)
    show_frame()

def show_frame():
#    if video_btn1.cget('text') == "Stop Video":
    global time_lapse_counter
    ret, frame = root.cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1) #flip image
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img) #converts img into tkinter readable format
        root.video_label.imgtk = imgtk
        root.video_label.configure(image=imgtk)
        if time_lapse_counter >= 20: # for Every 20 frames, capture one into time_lapse_list
            time_lapse_list.append(imgtk)
            time_lapse_counter = 0
        if len(time_lapse_list) == 100: # keep 99 frames in the list
            time_lapse_list.pop(0)
        time_lapse_counter += 1
        video_loop = root.after(40, show_frame)
    else:
        root.video_btn1.configure(text = "Start Video")

def time_lapse_play():
    root.cap.release() #stop capturing video.
    global frame_counter
    if frame_counter <= len(time_lapse_list)-1:
        imgtk = time_lapse_list[frame_counter] # get image from list
        root.video_label.configure(image=imgtk) # update label with image from list
        frame_counter += 1
        video_loop = root.after(250, time_lapse_play) #wait 250ms until next frame
    else:
        frame_counter = 0 #reset frame_counter

def setup_widgets(): #simple label and 2 button widget setup
    #Setup Top Right Window with pictures
    f_width, f_height = 1200, 500
    root.rightframe= Frame(root, border=0, width=f_width, height = f_height)
    root.rightframe.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=0)
    # Show video in Right Frame
    root.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    root.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 400)
    root.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 400)
    root.video_label = Label(root.rightframe)
    root.video_label.grid(row=0, column = 0)
    root.video_btn1 = Button(root.rightframe, fg='maroon', bg="yellow", text = 
"Stop Video", font=("Arial",10),height=0, width = 10, command=video_button1)
    root.video_btn1.grid(row=0, column = 1)
    root.video_btn2 = Button(root.rightframe, fg='maroon', bg="yellow", text="Time Lapse", font=("Arial",10),height=0, width = 10, command=time_lapse_play)
    root.video_btn2.grid(row=1, column = 1)
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root.rightframe)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=700,y=0)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().config(border=2, bg="yellow", width=400, height=400)

# Main Code
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
screen_resolution = str(screen_width)+'x'+str(screen_height)
root.geometry(screen_resolution)
time_lapse_counter = 0
frame_counter = 0
time_lapse_list=[]
setup_widgets()
show_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

`